# Parameterizing Scala Method With Parameterized Generic Class Fails

Tags: scala, oop

This:

```
trait SimpleJob[+T <: Serializable, +R <: Serializable]  {
  def dostuff[T](message : T) : R
}

object SimpleJob {
  def get_or_create_job(name : String) = print("do stuff")

  def apply[T, R](name : String, message : T) : Future[R] = Future{"do stuff".asInstanceOf[R]}

  def apply[S <: SimpleJob[T, R]](message : T) : Future[R] = this(classOf[S].getName, message)
}
```

Fails to compile because the compiler cannot resolve T, R, or S in the second apply method.

*Note on the example: I've taken out all of the function bodies to make this minimally reproducible. This example will fail if R is not a String. If anyone is interested, what I was attempted to do was make a structure for a limited form of type-safe Akka actor. The idea was that SimpleJob could be subclassed and parameterized, and then messages to all of the subclass actors would be passed through this object with calls of the form SimpleJob[ActorSubclassType].apply(message), where the parameter and return value would be type-safe. The apply methods were to check if an actor for the given class had already been instantiated, created it if it had not, and then pass the message and return a Future for the reply.  This turned out not to be feasible for a number of reasons, but along the way I realized there was something I didn't understand about scala's inhereitance system and I'm trying to find out what that is so I don't go down similar rabbit holes again.*

If I add two parameters like this:

```
def apply[S <: SimpleJob[T, R], T, R](message : T) : Future[R] = this(classOf[S].getName, message)
```

it compiles, but I want to be able to parameterize the function with only the one type, since it completely resolves the other types.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me understand what I'm apparently misunderstanding about scala's type system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dostuff[T]` is shadowing `T` type parameter from `SimpleJob`

Comment: Yes it is... intentionally.  But so what?   The part failing to compile is the Object, and in this minimally reproducible example I've eliminated any references from the Object apply methods relying on the trait methods.

Comment: Your example doesn't make very much sense. `S.getClass` is impossible, because `S` is just the _name_ of the type. You can't do `String.getClass`, can you? `.getClass` is an instance method: you have to have a instance of `S` to call `.getClass` on it. `"do stuff".asInstanceOf[R]` doesn't make any sense either: if `R` is anything other than a String, it'll crash. There is no point in having a parameter, that can only have one value. 
I understand, you meant to simplify it for the sake of example, but it appears that you went to far: it doesn't explain what you are actually trying to do at all

Comment: @Dima - You're right about the S. I editing the question and I'd appreciate if you take a look once I've done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `def apply[T, R, S <: SimpleJob[T, R]](message: T): Future[R]` the `S` type is not used in the method arguments at all, which naturally does not allow the compiler to infer the concrete value of `S` given only the arguments and vice versa. If you were passing an instance of `SimpleJob` to the method, then the situation would be opposite - the compiler would be able to infer the argument types:

```
def apply[T, R, S <: SimpleJob[T, R]](sj: SimpleJob[T, R])
                                     (message: T): Future[R] = ???
```

Alternatively, you can use abstract type members instead of type parameters:

```
trait SimpleJob {
  type T <: Serializable
  type R <: Serializable
  def dostuff[T](message: T) : R
}

object SimpleJob {
  def apply[S <: SimpleJob](message: S#T)(implicit sct: ClassTag[S]): Future[S#R] = 
    Future { println(sct.runtimeClass.getName); ??? }
}
```

Note that you cannot use `classOf[S]` when `S` is a type parameter; generics in JVM are not reified, therefore you have to use the class tag machinery to work around it.

Comment: thanks!  I think that's a path on the way to a solution, and you've explained some of what I was missing.  But --- I really want to include T and R in the parameterization of the SimpleJob trait, because I want to define classes that parameterize SimpleJob.  So I'd like to have a DumbJob that extends SimpleJob[Int, String], where the end result is that if I call SimpleJob.apply[DumbJob](), the parameters and return value are strongly typed to Int and String, respectively.  Any suggestions?  Thanks again!

Comment: You still need to override the type members in the extending class, so if you do something like `class DumbJob extends SimpleJob { override type T = Int; override type R = String }` then you will get exactly what you're asking for.